# Removing history using BFG Cleaner not working

Tags: bfg-repo-cleaner

**Removing history of deleted folders using BFG**

I am using BFG to delete history of deleted folders completely from repo

git rev-list --all --objects -- path/to/the/directory/to/delete | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(rest)' | grep -Pe '^\w+ blob' | cut -d' ' -f1 > ./to-delete.txt
java -jar bfg.jar --no-blob-protection --strip-blobs-with-ids ./to-delete.txt

I got the list of object ids but when i pass the object Ids to bfg using below command it throws error

java -jar bfg.jar --no-blob-protection --strip-blobs-with-ids ./to-delete.txt

**Error:**
java.exe : Error: Option --strip-blobs-with-ids failed when given 'RCC.txt'. MainException: class org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException(**Invalid id: **??e 4 c 8 e 1 b b 1 7 8 2 4 8 7 1 9 2 9 9 b 0 1 5 b 1 5 0 8 3 9 2 7 b d e f f 5 b)
At G:\Dev_Migration_Scripts\RepoCleaner_New.ps1:29 char:35

Answer (score 1):

Try `bfg -B 1 --no-blob-protection`

Read the [BFG usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage) and [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html).

`git rm -r --cached .` removes all cache from Git. This always fix my problems.

There's `git reset --hard` which leaves only committed files, and `git clean -d -x -f` that removes untracked files including directories (-d) and files ignored by git (-x).

Read about `git rm` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm), about `git clean` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) and about `git reset` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

I know that the last ones are not from BFG, but they might help you.

Comment: Thanks. I already followed the above links but it didnt worked. I need to delete the history of already deleted folders (having subfolders)

Answer (score 0):

I used the same technique as you and had the same issue with BFG raising the the InvalidObjectIdException for the blob hashes generated using `git rev-list` and `git cat-file`

The issue is with the text file's encoding, if you look at the invalid id `**??e 4 c 8 e 1 b b 1 7 8 2 4 8 7 1 9 2 9 9 b 0 1 5 b 1 5 0 8 3 9 2 7 b d e f f 5 b` you can see the extra characters, it would just be `e4c8e1bb178248719299b015b15083927bdeff5b` if the hash was correct but not found.

In my case I used Notepad++ for filtering the blobs I wanted to remove and for some reason the encoding switched to `UCS-2 LE BOM`. Switching back to `UTF-8` fixed the issue.